# Initial Repaint issues and count neighbour issues

Tags: java, conways-game-of-life

I have been trying to make a simple Game of Life simulation to keep myself busy and have come into two issues.

One, my "board" isn't being painted to the JFrame when it is first initialised, but it will once the simulation has started.
Two, my countNeighbours code is not working. Or at least the observed output is not what is expected.

Here is the code:
Interface:-

```
public class UserInterface extends JFrame
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static Screen screen;
    private JPanel controls = new JPanel();
    private JButton start = new JButton("Start");
    private JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");
    private JSlider speed = new JSlider();

    Timer t;
    int tSpeed = (speed.getValue()*10)+1;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new UserInterface();
        screen.repaint();
    }

    public UserInterface()
    {
        super("Game of Life");
        setSize(600,600);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        screen = new Screen();
        add(screen,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        controls.add(start);
        controls.add(reset);
        controls.add(speed);

        add(controls,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setVisible(true);

        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if(start.getText().equals("Start"))
                {
                    t = new Timer();
                    start.setText("Stop");
                    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            tSpeed = (speed.getValue()*10)+1;
                            screen.tick();
                        }
                    },0,tSpeed);
                }
                else
                {
                    start.setText("Start");
                    t.cancel();             
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Screen:-

```
public class Screen extends JPanel
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Rules rules = new Rules();
    private int WIDTH;
    private int HEIGHT;

    public Screen()
    {
        repaint();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void tick()
    {
        WIDTH = UserInterface.screen.getWidth();
        HEIGHT = UserInterface.screen.getHeight();
        rules.tick();
        repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        boolean[][] b = rules.getBoard();
        for(int y = 0; y < rules.HEIGHT; y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < rules.WIDTH; x++)
            {
                if(b[x][y] == true) g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                else g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                int w = x*(WIDTH/rules.WIDTH);
                int wsize = (WIDTH/rules.WIDTH);
                int h = y*(HEIGHT/rules.HEIGHT);
                int hsize = (HEIGHT/rules.HEIGHT);
                g.fillRect(w,h,wsize,hsize);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Rules:-

```
public class Rules 
{
    public final int WIDTH = 100;
    public final int HEIGHT = 100;
    private boolean[][] board = new boolean[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
    private boolean[][] tempBoard = new boolean[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

    public Rules()
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
            {
                board[x][y] = false;
            }
        }
        board[5][3] = true;
        board[5][4] = true;
        board[6][3] = true;
        board[6][4] = true;
    }

    public void tick()
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
            {
                int n = countNeighbors(x,y);
                if(n>=4)
                {
                    tempBoard[x][y] = false;
                }
                else if(n == 2 || n == 3)
                {
                    tempBoard[x][y] = true;
                }
                else if(n<=1)
                {
                    tempBoard[x][y] = false;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
            {
                board[x][y] = tempBoard[x][y];
            }
        }
    }

    private int countNeighbors(int x, int y)
    {
        int n = 0;

        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                if(i == 1 && j == 1)
                {}
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if(board[x+1-i][y+1-j]==true)n++;
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return n;
    }

    public void alternate(int x, int y)
    {
        board[x][y] = !board[x][y];
    }

    public boolean[][] getBoard()
    {
        return board;
    }
}
```

I am slowly going mad and I can't find what I have done wrong. I would really appreciate anyone who could help me.

Comment: Let's start with the fact that your overriding `paint` of `JPanel` and NOT calling `super.paint`.  Instead, you should be overriding `paintComponent` and ensuring that you are calling `super.paintComponent` before you do any kind of custom painting.  Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the fact that your overriding `paint` of `JPanel` and NOT calling `super.paint`.

Instead, you should be overriding `paintComponent` and ensuring that you are calling `super.paintComponent` before you do any kind of custom painting.  Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Don't rely on `static` values, especially width and height, instead, your component should be supply size hints back to the system.  The problem is, it's very difficult to accurately calculate a frame size which takes into account the different frame decoration requirements.  Instead, have your component define it's preferred size and use the frame's `pack` method to take care of ensuring the frame size.

I'd also discourage the use of `java.util.Timer` in favor of `javax.swing.Timer` as there is less chance of violation of the single thread rules of Swing and less requirement to ensure that the model is synchorinsed against paints...